# ActionSheet handler not able to access class variable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, callback, handler

I'm doing some POC on Ionic Framework and I needed to use ActionSheet and ActionSheetController. Everything seems to work, however I encountered a strange error when I assign a handler a function that I defined in the class. What's strange is that it's able to call the function as I have put console log but it complains and throws an error if the function uses or references any class variable or services that I have injected. It says undefined for my services or class variables. See the code below:

```
addToFavorites() {
console.log('Adding to Favorites', this.game.id);
this.favorite = this.favoriteservice.addFavorite(this.game.id);
this.toastCtrl.create({
  message: this.game.id + ' added as favorite successfully',
  position: 'middle',
  duration: 3000}).present();
}

presentActionSheet() {
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'Select Actions',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Add To Favorites',
      handler: this.addToFavorites
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
}); 
actionSheet.present();
}
```

Both are functions defined inside the page class with favoriteService that I have injected and game being the class variable. What I found that it works flawlessly when I call addToFavorites like below:

```
presentActionSheet() {
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
  title: 'Select Actions',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Add To Favorites',
      handler: () => {
        this.addToFavorites();
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
}); 
actionSheet.present();
}
```

Can someone explain to me why one works and other didn't? What's the difference?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is the error that comes up when I use the syntax @ewizard suggested:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ title: string; buttons: ({ text: string; handler: void; } | { text: string; handler: () => void...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionSheetOptions'.
Types of property 'buttons' are incompatible.
Type '({ text: string; handler: void; } | { text: string; handler: () => void; } | { text: string; role...' is not assignable to type '(string | ActionSheetButton)[]'.
  Type '{ text: string; handler: void; } | { text: string; handler: () => void; } | { text: string; role:...' is not assignable to type 'string | ActionSheetButton'.
    Type '{ text: string; handler: void; }' is not assignable to type 'string | ActionSheetButton'.
      Type '{ text: string; handler: void; }' is not assignable to type 'ActionSheetButton'.
        Types of property 'handler' are incompatible.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type '() => boolean | void'.
```

Comment: if my answer was helpful please mark it as correct, thanks.

Comment: let me know when u are back on the same system and can read the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are missing the `()` in `handler: this.addToFavorites`. It should be:

`this.addToFavorites()`.

Comment: I tried but then it complains about the syntax. Now I don't remember what error it showed as I currently don't have access to system I was working on. I'll confirm the error once I get access to that. And I don't think syntax or missing () is the problem since it was able to call the function just couldn't access any of the class variables.

Comment: Updated the original post to reflect the error that VS code throws when I use the syntax you suggested.

Comment: the error makes me think that you cant do it this way and you need to use `() => { function() }` after `handler:`...where have you seen this being done?

Comment: I haven't sen it being done like I try to do but I just can't understand the rationale behind it. After all we are simply plugging the function and that too with a same signature, thought it should work.